How to use BoxContainer to line up three sprites
I have a BoxContainer in which I am trying to line up three Sprite2Ds and a button horizontally.  I have code to calculate the minimum width and height of the container based on the sizes of the child nodes, but the Node2D/Sprite2D nodes always stack on top of each other, while the button honors the configuration.
Is there a way to use a container to render three sprites in a row without manually calculating their positions or hard coding the overall width of the container?

(Note: the BoxContainer Anchor Preset is set to Center Top in its configuration within "Bags")

Sprites are of Node2D type whereas Containers are of Control type. They don't really mix well together in that sense. If you need to use a sprite in a BoxContainer, first add a TextureRect node, and then add the Sprite to the Texture field of that node. That will give you the layout that you want.
